# What should I do if I had a nightmare according to the Quran or Hadith?

Tags: sunnah, reference-request, dream

If I had nightmares, what should I do? What can I do to avoid nightmares?

Please provide answer from Quran or Hadith.

Comment: well there are lots of questions in this post which dont match each other. Please reduce the questions to make it more sensible.

Comment: I tried to do that, But i couldn't do that because i have an error said that the question doesn't has stackexchange standers :(.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a nightmares if you wake up you should blow thrice on his left

> The Prophet (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) said, "A good vision
>   (dream) is from Allah and a bad dream is from the Satan. He who sees
>   something in a dream that he dislikes, should blow thrice on his left,
>   must seek Allah's Refuge from the evil of the Satan (i.e., by saying:
>   A'udhu billahi minash-Shaitanir-Rajim). Then it will not harm him."
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].
>
> وعن أبى قتادة رضى الله عنه قال‏:‏ قال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم‏:‏
>   ‏"‏الرؤيا الصالحة -وفى رواية‏:‏ الرؤيا الحسنة- من الله، والحلم من
>   الشيطان، فمن رأى شيئاً يكره فلينفث عن شماله ثلاثاً، وليتعوذ من الشيطان
>   فإنها لا تضره‏"‏

Riyad as-Salihin

And you must don't tell anyone about it

> There came to him (the Holy Prophet) a desert Arab and said: I saw in
>   a dream that I had been beheaded and I had been following it (the
>   severed head). Allah's Apostle (may peace be upon him) reprimanded him
>   saying: Do not inform about the vain sporting of devil with you during
>   the night.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا قُتَيْبَةُ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا لَيْثٌ، ح وَحَدَّثَنَا
>   ابْنُ رُمْحٍ، أَخْبَرَنَا اللَّيْثُ، عَنْ أَبِي، الزُّبَيْرِ عَنْ
>   جَابِرٍ، عَنْ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم أَنَّهُ قَالَ
>   لأَعْرَابِيٍّ جَاءَهُ فَقَالَ إِنِّي حَلَمْتُ أَنَّ رَأْسِي قُطِعَ
>   فَأَنَا أَتَّبِعُهُ فَزَجَرَهُ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَقَالَ ‏
>   "‏ لاَ تُخْبِرْ بِتَلَعُّبِ الشَّيْطَانِ بِكَ فِي الْمَنَامِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏

And to avoid nightmares just read Athkar for sleeping like

> Whenever Messenger of Allah () went to bed, he would lie down on his
>   right side and recite: "Allahumma aslamtu nafsi ilaika, wa wajjahtu
>   wajhi ilaika, wa fawwadtu amri ilaika, wa 'alja'tu zahri ilaika,
>   raghbatan wa rahbatan ilaika, la malja'a wa la manja illa ilaika.
>   Amantu bikitabikal-ladhi anzalta, wa nabiyyikal-ladhi arsalta [O
>   Allah! I have submitted myself to You, I have turned my face to You,
>   committed my affairs to You, and depend on You for protection out of
>   desire for You and out of fear of You (expecting Your reward and
>   fearing Your punishment). There is no refuge and no place of safety
>   from You but with You. I believed in the Book You have revealed, and
>   in the Prophet You have sent (i.e., Muhammad ()).]"
>
> [Al-Bukhari].
>
> عن البراء بن عازب رضى الله عنهما قال‏:‏ كان رسول>  الله صلى الله عليه
>   وسلم ِإذا أوى إلى فراشه نام على شقه الأيمن، ثم قال‏:‏ ‏"‏ اللهم أسلمت
>   نفسي إليك، ووجهت وجهي إليك، وفوضت أمري إليك، وألجأت ظهري إليك، رغبة
>   ورهبة إليك، لا ملجأ ولا منجى منك إلا إليك‏.‏ آمنت بكتابك الذي أنزلت
>   ‏.‏ ونبيك الذي أرسلت‏"‏‏

Riyad as-Salihin

And before you sleep Tawatha'(Ablution) and sleep on your right side

> Messenger of Allah () directed me thus: "Whenever you go to bed,
>   perform Wudu' as you do for Salat then (before sleeping) recite: 'O
>   Allah! I have submitted myself to You, I have turned myself to You,
>   committed my affairs to You and sought Your refuge for protection out
>   of desire for You and fear of You (expecting Your reward and fearing
>   Your punishment). There is no refuge and no place of safety from You
>   but with You. I believe in the Book You have revealed and in the
>   Prophet () You have sent."' Messenger of Allah () added: "If anyone
>   recites these words and dies during the night, he will die on the true
>   Deen, and if he remains alive till the morning, he will obtain good.
>   And make this supplication your last words (before sleeping)."
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].