# Why shouldn't you tell anyone about nightmares?

Tags: dream

In this [video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PLyfPcUoivAtYLK6aIirYy65RieY1kCwBk&v=Ok-bLXlJ97Q), it stated to not speak about nightmares at all and don't narrate them to anyone.

**Why is that? Is there any problem with that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are narrations about the Prophet instructing us not to do so:

> It was reported that Abu Hurayrah said: “The Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: ‘If any one of you sees
>   something that he dislikes (in a dream), let him get up and pray, and
>   not tell people about it. (narrated by Muslim, 2263)
>
> It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Dreams are of three types:
>   glad tidings from Allaah, what is on a person’s mind, and frightening
>   dreams from the Shaytaan. If any of you sees a dream that he likes,
>   let him tell others of it if he wishes, but if he sees something that
>   he dislikes, he should not tell anyone about it, and he should get up
>   and pray.” (Saheeh Sunan Ibn Maajah, 3154)

There might be other narrations that stating the reason but none that I came across so far.

---

**Update**

The narration below, cited in [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-should-i-do-if-i-saw-a-nightmare) answer seems to state the reason, not sure if this is the only reason:

> Jabir reported Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) as saying:
>   There came to him (the Holy Prophet) a desert Arab and said: I saw in
>   a dream that I had been beheaded and I had been following it (the
>   severed head). Allah's Apostle (may peace be upon him) reprimanded him
>   saying: Do not inform about the vain sporting of devil with you during
>   the night. (Sahih Muslim Book 029, Hadith Number 5640)

Comment: While this maybe answers his question, it doesn't seem to answer the question **why** the Prophet instructed us not to do so. One speculation might be that people interpret the dream in the reality somehow, which just might to lead to much superstitions and other psychological negativity.

Comment: @Kilise your speculation is similar to that of mine but i'd rather leave out that which I am unsure of, will look into the scholars opinion on this, the OP asks why we shouldn't speak of such dreams to others, my response was that this is what we were instructed to

Comment: Yes I see. I understood the question in another way, "why we was instructed to do so in first place", but I might have misunderstood it, since he accepted your answer.

Comment: @Kilise, Your right either way, it is always better to provide a comprehensive answer, which I attempted to but have not found enough info :)