# Should I narrate my dreams to others?

Tags: dream

If I have a dream should I tell others?

Answer (score 2):

### If it is a good dream, then yes you should tell others but if it is a bad dream, don't tell others.

Sayeeduna Abu Saaed ul-Khudri Radiallahu Anhu narrates that he heard the Prophet of Allah(SAWS) say:

> "‏ إِذَا رَأَى أَحَدُكُمْ رُؤْيَا يُحِبُّهَا فَإِنَّمَا هِيَ مِنَ اللَّهِ، فَلْيَحْمَدِ اللَّهَ عَلَيْهَا، وَلْيُحَدِّثْ بِهَا، وَإِذَا رَأَى غَيْرَ ذَلِكَ مِمَّا يَكْرَهُ، فَإِنَّمَا هِيَ مِنَ الشَّيْطَانِ، فَلْيَسْتَعِذْ مِنْ شَرِّهَا، وَلاَ يَذْكُرْهَا لأَحَدٍ، فَإِنَّهَا لاَ تَضُرُّهُ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> > *‘When someone amongst you sees a good and pleasing dream, he should know that it is from Allah, and so he should praise an thank Allah,* ***and describe to others what he saw in his dream.*** *But if he sees something that he dislikes then it is from Shaitan, so he should seek refuge from Allah (SWA) from its evil and* ***should not mention it to anyone’.***
>
> <sup>- [Sahih Bukhari p.1034 v.2](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/91)</sup>

It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> "‏ الرُّؤْيَا ثَلاَثٌ فَبُشْرَى مِنَ اللَّهِ وَحَدِيثُ النَّفْسِ وَتَخْوِيفٌ مِنَ الشَّيْطَانِ فَإِذَا رَأَى أَحَدُكُمْ رُؤْيَا تُعْجِبُهُ فَلْيَقُصَّهَا إِنْ شَاءَ وَإِنْ رَأَى شَيْئًا يَكْرَهُهُ فَلاَ يَقُصَّهُ عَلَى أَحَدٍ وَلْيَقُمْ يُصَلِّي ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> > *“Dreams are of three types: glad tidings from Allaah, what is on a person’s mind, and frightening dreams from the Shaytaan. If any of you sees a dream that he likes,* ***let him tell others of it if he wishes,*** *but if he sees something that he dislikes,* ***he should not tell anyone about it,*** *and he should get up and pray.”*
>
> <sup>- [Sahih Sunan Ibn Maajah, 3154](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/35/14)</sup>

Based on the above ahadith, you should ***only*** **tell people about good dreams that you have**.

<sub>[This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40342/why-shouldnt-you-tell-anyone-about-nightmares) might be related.</sub>

And Allah knows best.